# How to install MongoDb 3+ on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apt, mongodb

I've read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) manual from the official website and did all the steps.

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10`
2. `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`

However when I do `apt-get -s install -y mongodb-org` it shows that it will install `Inst mongodb-org-server (2.6.9 mongodb:dist/mongodb [i386])` which is 2.6.9 and not 3.+.

I also tried to do `apt-get -s install -y mongodb-org=3.0.2` but it showed `E: Version '3.0.2' for 'mongodb-org' was not found`.

My Ubuntu version: `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`

Comment: ubuntu 32 or 64 bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why I was not able to install it is because MongoDb 3+ requires 64bit. It won't install on 32bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

As per the official MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), this what worked for me for Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit edition :-

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.6 mongodb-org-server=3.0.6 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.6 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.6 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.6
```